# Remove product images in zen cart

Tags: php, product, zen-cart

i searched a lot to get an idea about deleting product images in Zen-cart, but not getting the ay, can anyone guide me to remove images for any product in zen cart?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, go to edit product, you will find "`Delete Image?`". Select "`YES`" and click on preview and "update" in next page.